# Odoo12 - Open form in view mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, formview

I'm trying to open a form in view mode like sale.order forms in my custom module. I'm tring to explain better: When I save my record and re enter in it, this form view is in editable mode, and I need it in view mode.

I tried to call to my form with `<field name="target">current</field>` in my action, like others answers that I saw on internet, but it didn't change.

EDIT:

I fix it change kanban view to another that I copy from standard code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `readonly` mode to action values using `flags`:

```
'flags': {'mode': 'readonly'}
```

***EDIT:***

You can define a server action and execute a python code to return a custom action.

In the following example the sale order form  is opened in readonly mode:

```
<record id="action_sale_order_readonly" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Sale Order</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">
form_view = env.ref('sale.view_order_form')
action = {
        'name': 'Sale Order',
        'res_model': 'sale.order',
        'views': [(form_view.id, 'form'),],
        'view_mode': 'form,tree,kanban',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'current',
        'flags': {'mode': 'readonly'}
    }
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: This could be used in action when I call form from .py but I'm calling this form from menuitem record.

Comment: Check my edit.I added an example of a server action.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I fix it change my kanban view! Thx for all! :D